# $z_{1}$ is parallel to the vector $z_2$ if and only if Im($z_1\bar z_2) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Can anyone please check the converse proof. And help me on the forward proof?

Exercise:

Show that the vector $z_{1}$ is parallel to the vector $z_2$ if and only if Im($z_1\bar z_2) = 0$

**converse proof:** Suppose Im($z_1\bar z_2) = 0$.

Then arg($z_1\bar z_2) = k\pi$ for $k = 0,1,-1,...,-n,n$.

arg($z_1\bar z_2)$ = arg($z_1$) - arg($z_ 2$) = $k\pi$

Then  arg($z_ 2$) = $k\pi + $ arg($z_1$).

Thus, the vectors $z_1, z_2$ are parallel.

**forward proof**: Suppose $z_1, z_2$ are parallel, then $z_1$ is prallel to $z_2$ if and only if $z_1 = cz_2$ for any real number $c$.

Then $z_1\bar z_2 = cz_2\bar z_2$.

Can someone please help  me? I am confuse about the conjugate part.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "parallel" seems a little confusing when talking of two *points* in the plane. I'd rather say they are "linearly dependent over the reals" or something like that.

So assume that for **some** (not "any") $\;c\in\Bbb R\;$ we have $\;z_1=cz_2\;$ , then:

$$z_1\overline{z_2}=cz_2\overline{z_2}=c|z_2|^2\in\Bbb R\implies \text{Im}\,(z_1\overline{z_2})=0$$

using that $\;w\overline w=|w|^2\;$ for any $\;w\in\Bbb C\;$